# Office yellow popup events for "checkout" button

Tags: c#, events, ms-office, office-addins

I am looking for single thing. I need get an event for this button in office add-in scope:

[image]

Any ideas? There is not simple event I have looked everywhere... but maybe I missed something

Answer (score 1):

The ribbon control Id/Name is FileCheckOut. I guess you can grab hold of the control from the ribbon and do it that way.

```
public void FileCheckIn_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control, ref bool cancelDefault)
{ 
}
```

http://tugbayatilla.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/vsto-microsoft-office-excel-ribbon.html

Comment: You know how to register this event?

Comment: Not sure, but have a look at this. Looks like you need to use a command binding in the Ribbon XAML http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/799395aa-4547-4cb3-9624-5c27a27e1a29/how-to-overload-sharepoint-filecheckin-operation-in-vsto?forum=vsto

Comment: your method is fine, but it cant be done by VSTO, it is just blocked.

Comment: Sorry, my ideas are spent now